# Bind to a command located in a behavior class

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a Gesture Recognizers with a command located in my MainPage.xaml :

```
<Image x:Name="SwipeButton" Source="baseline_more_horiz_24.xml" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="25">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.SfBehavior.SwipeButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference Main}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

I have a command in my Behavior class :

```
public Command<int> SwipeButtonCommand
{
     get { return swipeButtonCommand; }
     protected set { swipeButtonCommand = value; }
}
```

I want to bind my SwipeButton Gesture Recognizers Event command with the SwipeButtonCommand located inside my Behavior class

I tried to create an instance in MainPage.cs With property but it doesn't work :

```
public SfBehavior SfBehavior { get; set; }

SfBehavior = new SfBehavior();
```

***Update :***

I made the command binding on the page Main itself then I tried to bind on the SfBehavior property located in MainPage.cs like this

```
Main.BindingContext = this;

x:Class="Pdf.Views.MainPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" x:Name="Main">
```

Comment: you don't need to included "BindingContext" in the binding path

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately my binding still doesn't work

Comment: None of the properties are raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` event in the code. So it wont work